# @ManyToOne accross schemas creates wrong FK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, mariadb

I want my Users to be always stored in a central schema and thus hardcode it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "central")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "usr_id")
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

The following entity is located in other *local* schemas (defined by business logic) and references the central user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "prs_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "prs_usr_id")
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

Hibernate now does **not** automatically create the expected foreign key constraint pointing to *central*:

```
CONSTRAINT `...` FOREIGN KEY (`prs_usr_id`) REFERENCES central.user (`usr_id`);
```

instead a local user table is created and the FK references the local table.

What am I doing wrong?